# Use GraphQL to get ACF Flexible content from WP in Gatsby.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am using Gatsby.js in conjunction with the Wordpress plugin to query the Wordpress REST-API. I am having trouble working out how to use the results of one query to create another dynamic query which effectively loops over the returned array.

As I am using ACF Flexible Content in wordpress, I am unable to know the structure of the data prior to make the first query. The first query returns an array of the __typenames of flexible layout that have been added in the CMS, I then do a second query which returns the IDs of each of the above mentioned layouts.

This is where I run in to a brick wall- how do I loop through the IDs array and using the now known __typename make a query to get all of the fields listed within the ACF Flexible content?

```
 {
   wordpressPage(title : {eq:"About"}) {
     acf {
       components_page {
         __typename  
         // This returns an array of types 
         // eg [ 
         //     __typename : WordPressAcf_image_and_copy,
         //     __typename : WordPressAcf_body_copy
         //    ]
       }
     }
     children {
       id 
       // This returns an array of IDs 
       // eg [ 
       //     id : 4d2dac46-889e-593b-a00b-4a5ccaa87dfa2componentsWordPressAcf_image_and_copy, 
       //     id : 4d2dac46-889e-593b-a00b-4a5ccaa87dfa1componentsWordPressAcf_body_copy
       //    ]
     }
   }

   /* 
   ** This is the kind of query that I need to generate dynamically
   ** using the type returned above along with the ID returned above :
   */
   wordPressAcfImageAndCopy(id : {eq: "4d2dac46-889e-593b-a00b-4a5ccaa87dfa3componentsWordPressAcf_image_and_copy"}) {
     title
     subtitle
     body_copy
   }
 }
```

Apologies if I have not explained this very clearly- I appreciate any pointers anybody can give.

Comment: For anybody who happens upon this post in the future looking to resolve a similar problem, my question was very kindly answered here : https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3084 by https://github.com/pieh

Answer (score 2):

The solution from [github.com/pieh](https://github.com/pieh) posted on the [issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3084#issuecomment-348178908) is:

```
query homeQuery {
  wordpressPage(title: {eq: "About"}) {
    children {
      __typename
      ... on WordPressAcf_hero {
        title
        subtitle
      }
    }
  }
}
```